# Put . after n equal symbols

Tags: vim, sed, vi

In my case I want to divide text in 3500 symbols 
"text . in 3500"

```
%s/\(.\{3500\}\)\(.*\)/\1\.\2/

E486: Pattern not found: \(.\{3500\}\)\(.*\)
```

It works on the previous text but does not work on the next one.

Comment: What about enhancing your question with a reduced test case? And a before/after sample?

Comment: up romainl, and btw, `.{3500}` doesn't mean 3500 **equal symbols**. it could be `abcdefg....whatever.3500..foo`

Answer (score 1):

```
cat tmp
```

this is first line

now second line

finally third line

```
 cat tmp | sed ':a;N;$\!ba;s/\(.\{3\}\)/\1\./g'
```

thi.s i.s f.irs.t l.ine.

no.w s.eco.nd .lin.e

f.ina.lly. th.ird. li.ne

replace 3 with 3500 and see what happens +

Comment: cat bz.txt | sed ':a;N;$\!ba;s/\(.\{3\}\)/\1\./g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: `\'

Comment: cat bz.txt | sed ':a;N;$! ba;s/(.\{3\})/\1\./g' try this

Comment: cat ev1.txt | sed ':a;N;$! ba;s/(.\{3\})/\1\./g'sed: -e expression #1, char 28: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS >OKAY.. so it doesn't work